# why is there a black spot right on my mesh?

Tags: modeling

Ive tried joining the faces but it just gets worse. I've also tried sculpting. And for some reason the decimate modifier doesn't count any faces.[image: smooth shaded and non smooth shaded model]

Comment: Looks like inverted normals. Try selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then select `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`

Comment: It did nothing but thank you

Comment: Could you share your file so we can take a closer look at the problem?

Comment: maybe inner faces, overlapping faces or vertices?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the file